# Curve wrapping around a cone projecting symmetric hyperbolas on the XY plane quadrant

Tags: differential-geometry, 3d, parametric

Imagine a *cone* (of infinite height) with the vertex in the origin of a *3d*
system.
The cone is cut in 2 equal parts by the *XY* plane.

[Points of the *XY* plane, can be interpreted as complex numbers,
or just as pairs *(X, Y)*, whatever is more convenient.]

Now my question is: does exist a *3d* curve starting from the origin (cone vertex) and
wrapping around the cone (say, in a way possibly similar to a sort of "slanted" *conic spiral*)
such that, if we consider the *projection* on the plane *XY* of each Z-positive "half spiral", it comes out to be a hyperbola *symmetric* with respect to the *y = x* line, at least in the first quadrant of the XY plane?

I am wondering if such a curve exists, has a name, and, if yes, what is a general
form it could take (possibly as *parametric representation*, or complex function,
whatever is more convenient or elegant to use)?

PS.
I am looking for a unique continuous curve going around the cone (similar to a conic spiral), say something like: (x(theta), y(theta), z(theta) ) giving rise to all these symmetric hyperbolic projections on **XY first quadrant**. Imagine a point that starts from the origin and moves in some sort of *spiral* towards infinity, in such a way to project those **symmetric** hyperbolas on plane XY (wrt *y=x*), at least when it traverses the "positive half" of each loop (it can use the second, "negative half", to "advance", in whatever way).

Comment: If I understand your question, that curve should be the intersection between a cone with equation $x^2+y^2=az^2$ and a hyperbolic cylinder with equation $xy=k$. I don't think it has a name but a parametric equation is not difficult to find: $$\left(x, {a\over x}, \sqrt{x^4+k^2\over ax^2}\right).$$

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca Thanks a lot for the suggestion. So the hyperbolic cylinder when cutting the cone would still give hyperbolic sections I guess. I am going to check out your useful suggestion with some 3d tools, as right now I am not sure I can really "visualize" it.

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca I am looking for a 3d curve generating infinite hyperbolas, like some sort of conic "spiral" around the cone so that we get larger and larger hyperbolas as projections on XY. So in a parametric representation, we should need a fourth parameter (an angle I guess).

Comment: In other words, I was looking for a unique curve ( x(theta), y(theta), z(theta) ) giving rise to all these symmetric hyperbolic projections.

Comment: To get all hyperbolas just change parameter $k$.

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca Yes, Thank you I think I understood that by changing k we might get different "parallel" sections of the cone. However, for my animation, I was looking for a point starting from the origin and moving continuously in a sort of spiral in such a way to project those symmetric hyperbolas on xy.  The point should be able to move smoothly from a section to another continuously. I guess that in order to achieve that, the parameter should be an angle of rotation.

Comment: OK, I thought all hyperbolas had to be symmetric about line $y=x$. To achieve your goal you should add a rotation about $z$ axis: $$\left(x\cos\theta -{a\over x}\sin\theta, x\sin\theta +{a\over x}\cos\theta,\sqrt{x^4+k^2\over a x^2}\right).$$

Comment: And probably $k$ should also vary with $\theta$, depending on the effect you want.

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca Thank you. This seems more like it. Yes, the hyperbolas should be symmetric about line  y=x, but this is required only when the point is moving on positive Z ("positive half" of the loop) and only when the projection is within the first quadrant XY. When the point is moving elsewhere there is no need for any symmetry (just going for another loop forward).